# RangeValidator is allowing several decimal points

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, rangevalidator

If I enter a value of 1.2.1 into my RangeValidator below, it validates OK

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator8" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxSAPPlannedHrs" 
    Display="None" ErrorMessage="Must be a valid number 0-999"
    MaximumValue="999" MinimumValue="0"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

How can this be classed as a valid range. 1.2.1 is not a valid number...

Comment: I think the widget is using `string` as the datatype.  Try adding `Type="Double"` or `Type="Int"` to the tags.

Comment: Of course it is. It depends on the current culture. This is 121.0: `double.Parse("1.2.1", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));`. So if your current culture uses dot as group separator it is a valid number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default if the `Type` is not specified I think it uses the `String` as the default conversion type before doing the compare.

Change your control to the following:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxSAPPlannedHrs" 
    Display="None" ErrorMessage="Must be a valid number 0-999"  MaximumValue="999"
    MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

This will cause the input to be converted to the type specified (`Integer`) before doing the compare.  If the conversion fails, the validation will fail.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.rangevalidator.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The values are implicitly converted to the specified data type before
>   the comparison is made. If the data conversion fails, data validation
>   fails.